# NoSQL dbs: How do we handle methods that are part of the Models in ORMs?

Tags: nosql

I read that some people find it wrong to use a ORM with NoSQL databases and I guess it is correct, because the thing is we use **non-relational** databases, so it seems wrong to map a **relational** mapping around them.

But what to do with our models? When we had ORM, we had something like this (for a database table *events*):

```python
class Event():
    def isVeryNew():
        if this.date < now - 60:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Now when I should avoid ORM, how would I call such methods on my data? Should I create methods and pass the retrieve data to it? Like this:

```python
def event_is_very_new(data):
    if "date" in data and data["date"] < now - 60:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

### Background

I have been wondering, because I am diving into Django and want to use it with MongoDB, but I struggle to use it with any of the two or three ORM mappers. So I watched the pure pyMongo example which does [not define any models at all](https://github.com/mdirolf/DjanMon/blob/master/status/models.py)

```python
# from django.db import models

# We don't need models with MongoDB. If you really *want* models check out
# something like MongoKit (http://bitbucket.org/namlook/mongokit/) to add
# an ORM-ish layer on top of PyMongo.
```